# Social auth login using JWT in Django - This authorization code has expired

Tags: python-social-auth, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-gis

I am a Python newbie and I want to integrate the functionality for social login in my Django project, using JWT authentication. I used [this](https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth) package, but the documentation of this project is not good. It shows that I need to send an object `{ 'provider' : '', 'code' : '' }` to the endpoint to get a JWT token. But I am not able to understand how I will get this code for Facebook, Twitter, Google etc.

I got a code as response from Facebook by hitting the Facebook oauth url but when I used it in object for endpoint it always show this error:

```
Authentication process canceled

{
  'error': {
    'message': 'This authorization code has expired.', 
    'type': 'OAuthException', 
    'code': 100, 
    'fbtrace_id': 'A7njJL6BTqXbji1TC5Xl1Us'
  }
}

Bad Request: /api/login/social/jwt/
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Rahul, please add a bit more context as to what you are trying to do and provide some code samples if possible. From the error message I'm assuming you are trying to authenticate using Facebook? Please mention what configuration you've done so that other might help figure out what's going wrong.

Also, use the formatting tools to format your code and errors into code blocks to make everything easier to read.

Comment: Hi @MariusBughiu thanks for the reply. Sorry to provide very less info about the problem. I edited the question, please check it now.

Comment: That's ok Rahul. I've updated your question to make it easier to read & formatted the code & error in code blocks. I don't have experience with Django so I'm not of much help here, but I did a search in the GitHub repo of the package you mentioned and there's someone who was having your error exactly and it was because of an expired token but they don't provide very much details (https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth/issues/22). I'm guessing it would help others if you would provide some sample code to determine how you're trying to login.